# Add new Environment Variable Name and Value

Tags: excel, vba, environment, environ

I wanted to set a new Environment Variables Name "Sample" and Value "E:\Sample" onto user variables not on system variables.

How do I do this using VBA excel?

Thank you and kind regards,

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub addEnvironVariables()

    Dim WSS: Set WSS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set System = WSS.Environment("User")
    System.Item("Sample") = System.Item("Sample") & ";C:\Sample"

End Sub
```

Found it on youtube

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me the following steps worked (Excel 2019)

To create/set an environment variable:

```
Dim objUserEnvVars As Object
Set objUserEnvVars = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("User")
objUserEnvVars.item("Test") = "Blah"
```

To read the environment variable:

```
Dim objUserEnvVars As Object
Dim strVar As String
Set objUserEnvVars = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("User")
strVar = objUserEnvVars.item("Test")
MsgBox strVar
```

My reference is: https://eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4857

You can use on `.Environment()` to save your variable:

- `"System"`: Returns the system environment variables.
- `"User"`: Returns the current user's environment variables.
- `"Process"`: Returns the environment variables of the current process.
- `"Volatile"`: Returns the current user's volatile environment variables.